# Why does the Java compiler sometimes allow the unboxing of null?

Tags: java, compilation, javac, unboxing

For example:

```
int anInt = null;
```

fails at compile time but

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("" + getSomeVal());
  }
}
public static int getSomeVal() {
   return new Random().nextBoolean() ? 1 : null;
}
```

fails (usually) at run time. Trying to return just `null` will also result in a compile error, so I assume there is something about having multiple paths that causes the compiler to infer that `null` is potentially an autoboxed `int`?  Why can javac not fail to compile both cases with the same error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the first case, the compiler knows that you're trying to unbox a compile-time constant of `null`.

In the second case, the type of the conditional expression is `Integer`, so you're effectively writing:

```
Integer tmp = new Random().nextBoolean() ? 1 : null;
return (int) tmp;
```

... so the unboxing isn't happening on a constant expression, and the compiler will allow it.

If you changed it to force the conditional expression to be of type `int` by unboxing *there*, it would fail:

```
// Compile-time failure
return new Random().nextBoolean() ? 1 : (int) null;
```

Comment: The first case involves a null "type" being implicitly cast to an int type, resulting in a compiler error. The second case implicitly casts null to the left hand variable type, which is the type of the expression rather than the return value. I guess a careful reading of JLS 15.25 "If the second and third operands have the same type (which may be the null type), then that is the type of the conditional expression." gives you this, as the java compiler cannot give null a type of int and so is forced to use Integer for both by unboxing the 1. Very clear answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Boxing partially hides the distinction between primitives and corresponding wrapper objects, but it doesn't remove it.

There are two distinctions which are not changed by boxing:

- objects can be null, while primitives cannot
- objects have both state and identity, while primitives have only state (the value)

Occasionally, these differences can cause problems when using boxing.

Some points to remember :

- be careful with nulls. Auto-unboxing a null object will cause a `NullPointerException`.
- comparing items with `==` and `equals` must be done with care.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign null to an int

```
    int anInt = null;
```

Java allows this since you are not assigning null to an int

```
    System.out.println("" + getSomeVal()); //null was just converted to a srting and was printed
```

If you perform this, you can get the error

```
    int anInt = getSomeVal();
```