# NullPointerException when adding to HashMap

Tags: java

I am getting a NullPointerException when adding data to a HashMap. I am writing a class to count the given frequencies of certain Objects. Here is my code (stripped of any unnecessary details):

```
public class FrequencyCounter {

    private Map<Object, Integer> freq;

    public FrequencyCounter() {
        freq = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
    }

    public int add(Object key) {        
        System.out.println("Map is null: " + (freq == null));
        System.out.println("Key is null: " + (key == null));
        if (freq.containsKey(key)) {
            return freq.put(key, freq.get(key) + 1);
        }
        return freq.put(key, 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FrequencyCounter fc = new FrequencyCounter();
        fc.add(new Object());
    }
}
```

The NPE is occuring on the line `return freq.put(key, 1);` Both println statements print false.

Do any of you know what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: null pointer exception when unboxing Integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811706/java-null-pointer-exception-when-unboxing-integer)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is because `HashMap.put(key, value)` will return the previous value associated with key, or null.
In your code, you cannot return `freq.put(key,1)` as int because it is null.

Comment: I added a print statement to check if `freq.put(key, 1)` was returning null and it was. Thank you.

Comment: I'm wonder, why there is no compile time error, in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html such condition is not provided

Comment: @atomAltera I think this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897883/why-does-the-java-compiler-sometimes-allow-the-unboxing-of-null

Comment: @atomAltera The compiler cannot know It is null because `freq.put(key, 1)` will return a Integer object.

Comment: @locoyou Yes, but this Integer object (more precisely - pointer to Integer object) could point to nothing. But I think java developers doing this right, I mean implicit unboxing

Answer (score 2):

add method returns int. int is primitive data type , which can not be null. freq.put(key,1)returns null so it throws exception. change return type of add method to Integer or add null check.

Comment: That's what I did, thanks. I just returned `0` because prior to this, the given object was present in the Map `0` times.

Answer (score 1):

since `put()` may return null so you must change return type to `Integer` which can be null:

```
public Integer add(Object key) {        
    System.out.println("Map is null: " + (freq == null));
    System.out.println("Key is null: " + (key == null));
    if (freq.containsKey(key)) {
        return freq.put(key, freq.get(key) + 1);
    }
    return freq.put(key, 1);
}
```

and must validate return value for null before using it.